# get specific data using volley

Tags: php, android, google-maps, mysqli, android-volley

I want to get specific data latitude and longitude data from mysql to implement it to map using volley.
I'm using spinner to get spesific data and in `setOnItemSelectedListener` and use volley to get data. But it's not working to get the data.

this is my code:

```
String[] jenisATM = {"-- Pilih ATM --","ATM BNI", "ATM BCA", "ATM Mandiri"};
        Spinner spinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, jenisATM);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() != "-- Pilih ATM --"){

                    mMap.clear();

                    final String pilih_atm = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();

                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_GET_ATM,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                                        result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                                        for (int i = 0 ; i<jsonObject.length() ; i++){

                                            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(i);

                                            String atm_name = json.getString("atm_name");
                                            String koordinat = json.getString("koordinat");
                                            String jenis = json.getString("jenis");

                                            String[] arrKoordinat = koordinat.split(",");
                                            double lat_atm = Double.parseDouble(arrKoordinat[0]);
                                            double lng_atm = Double.parseDouble(arrKoordinat[1]);

                                            endx = new LatLng(lat_atm, lng_atm);

                                            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                                            options.position(endx);
                                            options.title(atm_name);
                                            if (jenis.equals("ATM BNI")){
                                                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                                            }else if(jenis.equals("ATM BCA")){
                                                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                                            }else if(jenis.equals("ATM Mandiri")){
                                                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
                                            }

                                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(options);

                                            marker.setTag(endx);
                                        }



                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gagal Mengambil Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gagal Mengambil Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            })
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put("jenis", pilih_atm);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include 'Koneksi.php';

$koneksi = new Koneksi();
$conn = $koneksi->connect();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {
    $jenis = $_GET['jenis'];

    $json= array();

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM atm WHERE jenis ='$jenis'") or die("Error ". mysqli_error($conn));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp['id'] = $row['id'];
        $temp['atm_name'] = $row['atm_name'];
        $temp['koordinat'] = $row['koordinat'];
        $temp['jenis'] = $row['jenis'];

        array_push($json, $temp);
    }

    echo json_encode(array('data' => $json));   
}
```

when I run the with url `localhost/go-atm/index.php?jenis=ATM BNI` it work and give me a json file like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the exact exception?

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is i cant get data from mysql to my make markers in map. it gave me `JSONException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be "result.length" in place of "jsonObject.length" in for loop